# Gradle error after git clone

Tags: android, git, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Git and Android studio. Basically I have a working android studio project which I pushed on my home computer and expected to do a simple pull at work and continue my work.

Unfortunately I am getting this error message and cannot run my project:

```
3:45:27 PM Migrate Project to Gradle?
           This project does not use the Gradle build system. We recommend that you migrate to using the Gradle build system.
           More Information about migrating to Gradle
           Don't show this message again.
```

The message is suggesting the project does not use gradle, when in fact...this project does use Gradle on my home computer.

Comment: Does the root of your project contain the build.gradle file? And, if not, can you copy it into there manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I would remove following files/directories from your project-folder:

```
bin/
build/
.idea/
.gradle/
projectname.iml
```

Then try to import the project again in AndroidStudio. This usually works for me, and to avoid that in the future, adjust the .gitignore file properly.

If the first tip does not help: have you tried downloading a more recent gradle (1.12) locally and point to that directory? (Don't point AndroidStudio to download, but do it yourself first). You are not using a gradle-wrapper are you?

Comment: Ok let me try that out...No Iam not using gradle-wrapper.

Comment: Gradle 1.12 is hardly recent... Try 2.4!
Also, if you're working on two different machines, it may be very useful to have the gradle wrapper, to avoid just the type of problem where the two machines have different versions installed. The wrapper ensures that they are always in sync.